# Watir Webdriver(0.9.1) No Longer Opens an Instance of Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

While using Watir Webdriver v0.9.1 for rails (along with Selenium Webdriver 2.53.1), Firefox was opening when

```
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

was called. Now however, it fails on that line with

```
unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45 seconds
    @ /Users/andmcadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:59:in `lock'
      /Users/andmcadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:40:in `locked'
      /Users/andmcadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:51:in `launch'
      /Users/andmcadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:43:in `initialize'
      /Users/andmcadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in `new'
      /Users/andmcadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:53:in `for'
      /Users/andmcadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:84:in `for'
      /Users/andmcadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
      test/integration/like_fanpage_task_test.rb:40:in `new'
      test/integration/like_fanpage_task_test.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <class:LikeFanpageTaskTest>'
```

It seemed to do so randomly, as I did not change the code from its working form and that line is the first line called. I have Firefox 37.0.2, which worked earlier. I have tried restarting my computer, killing processes related to ruby and Firefox and starting them again, and reinstalling Firefox but to no avail.

Comment: Seems like you have FF instance but without visible window. So, close all Firefox instances and check that they doesn't run use `ps aux | grep firefox` command. If you see other firefox instances then kill them or reboot comp.

Comment: Whenever I try to kill the process using `sudo kill -9 PID` it still shows up when using `ps aux | grep firefox` but with a PID two greater than the last time and Watir still won't open Firefox.

Comment: > While using Watir Webdriver v0.9.1 Your stack trace shows you are running `watir-webdriver-0.6.2`
Lots have changes have been made since then.

Comment: Good catch, I was testing it with 0.6.2 to make sure I hadn't accidentally upgraded but forgot to change it back. My post now shows the error with Watir 0.9.1

Comment: Hmm, default port for Firefox is 7055, so I'm not sure how you get 7054 when the Selenium code does: `port += 1 until free? port`. Set $DEBUG = true and add a gist with your stdout.

Comment: I've caught pretty similar issue about 2 days ago. Are you using 47 version of Firefox? If so try to downgrade to 46. 46 is working for me. That is not "The Answer". But if it will work it will be more easy to try to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mozilla has introduced a new webdriver, and due to a bug in firefox 47, only the new webdriver works for firefox. However I would suggest permanently switching to the new webdriver either way as support will be fully dropped as of firefox 48.

You can use the new webdriver in ruby using the following:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, marionette: true
```

But I don't know if that would make you able to use it in watir as well.

As far as I can tell marionette (the new driver) support is not completed yet in watir (I could be wrong), I see [this](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/pull/395) pull request is dealing with it but it is not completed or merged.

It looks to me as if you can do:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :marionette
```

When the watir project is finished integrating the new driver.

Comment: I missed this discussion earlier. The right way to use Marionette with Watir currently is `Watir::Browser.new :firefox, marionette: true`. When Selenium 3.0 comes out and Watir updates to require it, Marionette will be the default option. That Pull Request has nothing to do with how Watir supports Marionette; Watir currently supports it to the extent that Selenium supports it. Since there are a number of commands that Watir relies on that aren't yet implemented in Marionette, there will be functionality missing.

Comment: It's also worth noting that updating to Firefox 47.0.1 and using selenium-webdriver gem 2.53.4 fixes this specific problem without needing to use Marionette, yet.

Answer (score 0):

PLease use latest webdriver selenium-webdriver.2.5.4 it is not available yet on seleniumhq but search for it.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted as it is essentially correct. You need selenium-webdriver gem 2.53.4 (commenter missed a 3 in there), in order for your tests to work with Firefox 47.0.1