# How to install and configure geckodriver on Rails / Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, watir

I'm using Watir to scrape in production, but due to some firefox issues, it no longer is able to launch a browser (see here [Watir Webdriver(0.9.1) No Longer Opens an Instance of Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800215/watir-webdriver0-9-1-no-longer-opens-an-instance-of-firefox)).

Gecko driver is here:  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver

How do I install geckodriver and configure rails to use it instead of the default firefox binary?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [official page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) with the directions.
Relevant portion for Ruby:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, marionette: true
```

or if using remote server:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox marionette: true
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Similar to chromedriver, make sure that geckodriver is in your PATH

As for:

> configure rails to use it

Do you mean Capybara?

Answer (score -1):

You can put it in `/usr/bin/`

```
$ unzip geckodriver_linux64.zip
$ sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo chmod +x chromedriver
```