# Unable to run a simple Watir script

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

I am trying to run a simple Watir script on my system but I am getting error. I tried with 2.2.4, 2.1.8 and 1.9.3 too but nothing works for me. I long time back I used to work on Watir on v1.8.7 and on some 2.x version, but now I can't remember what different I did back then.

Following is the code I tried to execute with v1.9.3 on Win7 x64bit.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
print "Hello"
b = Watir::Browser.start 'http://www.google.com'
```

With this I get the error "Unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)".

I tried using watir instead of 'watir-webdriver' but that also doesn't work.
watir, watir-webdriver, watirclassic and selenium-webdriver are installed.

Comment: It might be connected to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800215/watir-webdriver0-9-1-no-longer-opens-an-instance-of-firefox

Comment: As a workaround, there's always chrome: https://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/

Comment: Also, you can try geckodriver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver it's still mostly "beta," but it will be required for Firefox 48+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Mozilla bug in Firefox 47 that broke things. It has been fixed. Update your selenium-webdriver gem to 2.53.4 and it will work with Firefox 47.0.1

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, I almost spent one complete day looking for solution and all I actually needed was a simple firefox update. Thanks again. :)